# How to pass variables for a script via SNMP by using snmpget?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I have one simple bash script calls test_snmp, let's say:

```
#!/bin/bash
 echo $1
```

I have snmpd.conf set as following:

```
rwcommunity public 127.0.0.1
extend .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.53 /bin/bash /tmp/test_snmp
```

What I'd like to do is to run a snmpwalk command, something like:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.53 "PRINT SOMETHING"
```

from the output I see that
`oid = iso.3.6.1.4.1.2021.53.3.1.1.9.47.98.105.110.47.98.97.115.104 = ""`, is the output of the script. But I'd like to pass that string `"PRINT SOMETHING"`, as a `$1` parameter for the script mentioned above and then get the string (in this case `"PRINT SOMETHING"`) by using `snmpget` command, something like:

```
snmpget -v2c -c public 127.0.0.1 iso.3.6.1.4.1.2021.53.3.1.1.9.47.98.105.110.47.98.97.115.104
```

It is only an example, I'm testing what options I have by running scripts via snmp, because if this works then I'll write another scripts to run remotely, but I have to run them with variables.

Does anyone know how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I spent lot of time before found all answers. I hope, it will be start point for someone and will save time.

**/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf:**

```
rwcommunity public
pass .1.3.6.1.4.1.YOUR_NUM_HERE.1 /path/to/your/script.sh
```

**/path/to/your/script.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash 

case "$1" in
    -g) // GET Req
        echo $2 # ANSWER OID
        echo "string" # string/int/etc...
        echo "you data" #
    ;;
    -s)  // SET Req
    # Your code for processing SET Req
    exit 0
    ;;

    -n) // GETNEXT Req

        echo $2
        echo "string"
        # Your code for processing GETNEXT Req
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac
```

You can use **snmpwalk** after that and place your code after "-n" case. 
In case of **snmpget**, you code will be after "-g"